# Shuffling Elements in a List (randomly re-arrange List Elements)

Tags: erlang

Part of my program requires me to be able to randomly shuffle list elements. I need a function such that when i give it a list, it will pseudo-randomly re-arrange the elements in the list.
 A change in arrangement  **Must** be visible at each call with the same list. 
My implementation seems to work just fine but i feel that its rather long and is increasing my code base and also, i have a feeling that it ain't the best solution for doing this. So i need a much shorter implementation. Here is my implementation:

```
-module(shuffle).
-export([list/1]).
-define(RAND(X),random:uniform(X)).
-define(TUPLE(Y,Z,E),erlang:make_tuple(Y,Z,E)).

list(L)->    
    Len = length(L),
    Nums = lists:seq(1,Len),    
    tuple_to_list(?TUPLE(Len,[],shuffle(Nums,L,[]))).

shuffle([],_,Buffer)-> Buffer;
shuffle(Nums,[Head|Items],Buffer)->
    {Pos,NewNums} = pick_position(Nums),    
    shuffle(NewNums,Items,[{Pos,Head}|Buffer]).

pick_position([N])-> {N,[]};
pick_position(Nos)->
    T = lists:max(Nos), 
    pick(Nos,T).

pick(From,Max)->
    random:seed(begin
                    (case random:seed(now()) of 
                        undefined -> 
                            NN = element(3,now()),
                            {?RAND(NN),?RAND(NN),?RAND(NN)};
                        Any -> Any
                    end)
                end
                ),
    T2 = random:uniform(Max),
    case lists:member(T2,From) of
        false -> pick(From,Max);
        true -> {T2,From -- [T2]}
    end.
```

On running it in shell:

```
F:\> erl
Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(shuffle).
{ok,shuffle}
2> shuffle:list([a,b,c,d,e]).
[c,b,a,e,d]
3> shuffle:list([a,b,c,d,e]).
[e,c,b,d,a]
4> shuffle:list([a,b,c,d,e]).
[a,b,c,e,d]
5> shuffle:list([a,b,c,d,e]).
[b,c,a,d,e]
6> shuffle:list([a,b,c,d,e]).
[c,e,d,b,a]
```

I am motivated by the fact that in the **STDLIB** there is no such function. Somewhere in my game, i need to shuffle things up and also i need to find the best efficient solution to the problem, not just one that works.
Could some one help build a shorter version of the solution ? probably even more efficient ?   Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that [karl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820501/2457) is much more concise and simple.

---

Here's a fairly simple solution, although not necessarily the most efficient:

```
-module(shuffle).

-export([list/1]).

list([])     -> [];
list([Elem]) -> [Elem];
list(List)   -> list(List, length(List), []).

list([], 0, Result) ->
    Result;
list(List, Len, Result) ->
    {Elem, Rest} = nth_rest(random:uniform(Len), List),
    list(Rest, Len - 1, [Elem|Result]).

nth_rest(N, List) -> nth_rest(N, List, []).

nth_rest(1, [E|List], Prefix) -> {E, Prefix ++ List};
nth_rest(N, [E|List], Prefix) -> nth_rest(N - 1, List, [E|Prefix]).
```

For example, one could probably do away with the `++` operation in `nth_rest/3`. You don't need to seed the random algorithm in every call to `random`. Seed it initially when you start your program, like so: `random:seed(now())`. If you seed it for every call to `uniform/1` your results become skewed (try with `[shuffle:list([1,2,3]) || _ <- lists:seq(1, 100)]`).

Comment: Thanks @Adam great solution. I love it

Comment: hi. may I add that you should seed before using `random:uniform`? otherwise you will get the same results in different executions of the VM and in many applications this is unwanted.

Comment: @user601836 Good point! Note that you only need to do this once per process, and not for every run of `shuffle:list/1`.

Comment: Nice quadratic complexity but I would like O(N*logN) of [karl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1143327/karl)'s [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8820501/49197).

Comment: I would also add that most of the times it is better to use the seed proposed in LYSE: `{A:32,B:32,C:32} = crypto:rand_bytes(12)` as `random:seed({A,B,C})`

Answer (score 76):

```
1> L = lists:seq(1,10).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Associate a random number R with each element X in L by making a list of tuples {R, X}. Sort this list and unpack the tuples to get a shuffled version of L.

```
1> [X||{_,X} <- lists:sort([ {random:uniform(), N} || N <- L])].
[1,6,2,10,5,7,9,3,8,4]
2>
```

Comment: Voted up!,  i love this one too ! Thanks @karl

Comment: This method of shuffling produces biased results unless you can guarantee that no duplicate random numbers are generated (which you can not with `random:uniform/0`.

Comment: Good point @jvf, though I think it's worth pointing out that since `random:uniform/0` returns a float, duplicates should be extremely rare. Good to be conscious of this kind of thing, but I would wager that for many applications such a tiny amount of bias would not be an issue in practice.

Comment: Is there a better randomness function?

Comment: @quantumpotato Not sure what you mean by "better" but the new and improved version is `rand:uniform()`

Answer (score 1):

```
-module(shuffle).

-compile(export_all).

shuffle(L) ->
    shuffle(list_to_tuple(L), length(L)).

shuffle(T, 0)->
    tuple_to_list(T);
shuffle(T, Len)->
Rand = random:uniform(Len),
A = element(Len, T),
B = element(Rand, T),
T1 = setelement(Len, T,  B),
T2 = setelement(Rand,  T1, A),
shuffle(T2, Len - 1).
```

main()->
    shuffle(lists:seq(1, 10)).

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit faster than the above solution, listed here as do2 for timing comparison.

```
-module(shuffle).
-export([
    time/1,
    time2/1,
    do/1,
    do2/1
]).

time(N) ->
    L = lists:seq(1,N),
    {Time, _} = timer:tc(shuffle, do, [L]),
    Time.
time2(N) ->
    L = lists:seq(1,N),
    {Time, _} = timer:tc(shuffle, do2, [L]),
    Time.
do2(List) ->
    [X||{_,X} <- lists:sort([ {rand:uniform(), N} || N <- List])].
do(List) ->
    List2 = cut(List),
    AccInit = {[],[],[],[],[]},
    {L1,L2,L3,L4,L5} = lists:foldl(fun(E, Acc) -> 
        P = rand:uniform(5), 
        L = element(P, Acc),
        setelement(P, Acc, [E|L])
    end, AccInit, List2),
    lists:flatten([L1,L2,L3,L4,L5]).

cut(List) ->
    Rand=rand:uniform(length(List)),
    {A,B}=lists:split(Rand, List),
    B++A.
```