# How can I assign random number of list elements to a new list

Tags: list, erlang

I have a list like:

```
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
```

I want to pick a random selection of elements, 
Like:

```
L1=[[1,2,3],[9,10,11]]
L2=[[1,2,3]]
L3=[[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
L4=[[1,2,3]]
```

How can I do that in erlang?

Edit:
I want also to guaranty that all the elements will be at least selected once.

Comment: Sorry, I dont see a pattern in the results. What would `L4` be? Try to describe what you want to achieve in words instead of examples, this might even lead you to a solution by yourself...

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8817171/431620

Comment: In order to propose a good answer, you should give more information about the size of the elements of your main list, and the number of elements in that main list.

If the size of elements may be big, then you cannot keep the sublists in memory to check for duplicate, but you should keep a "codded" version of those sublists.

The length of the main list is more a concern. if this main list contains N elements, then the number of none empty combination is 2^n-1, that means that you will be out of memory very fast, just for tracking duplicates.

Comment: As the question is closed, i cannot propose my answer to your question, but I may send it to you by mail; mine is : pascalchap@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is take a list `[A, B, C, D, E]` and pick a random selection of elements, so sometimes you will get `[A, C, E]` and other times you will get `[B, C]`, other times just `[E]`, etc.  The fact that the elements are themselves lists does not appear to be significant in the example you gave.

Basically, the idea is to individually select each element with some probability P, which is equivalent to assigning each element a random number and then checking if it is less than P.  Most likely, P = 0.5 for your case -- each element has a 50/50 chance of being selected.

So, I think this will solve your problem.

```
random_subset(List) -> random_subset(List, 0.5).

random_subset(List, P) ->
    % Need to seed the random number generator
    {S1,S2,S3} = now(),
    random:seed(S1, S2, S3),
    % Assign a random value for each element in the list.
    Selections = [{E, random:uniform()} || E <- List],
    % Only keep elements where the random value is in the selected range
    [E || {E, RandomValue} <- Selections, RandomValue < P].
```

There are more compact ways to write this, but I did it the long way to explain each step of what is going on.  A simpler way to do this is to use [lists:filter/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2):

```
random_subset(List, P) ->
    % Note: assuming the random number generator has already been seeded
    lists:filter(fun(_) -> random:uniform() < P end, List).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I want, nut I want also to guaranty that all the elements, will be selected at least once. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "at least once"?  Are you saying you also want a random number of subsets and each element shows up in at least one subset?  The simplest way to modify that is to generate the random number of subsets first, say N.  Then, when you are generating the last subset, look for any that haven't been included yet (via lists:member or otherwise) and change that element's P value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [random](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/random.html) module to generate a new list of random length containing items randomly selected from L, eliminating duplicates if necessary.